# BIRT Reports - Traverse report elements

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

When opening a BIRT report inside Eclipse, you can see in the Outline view the report tree.

Is there a way to traverse the design just like that when having a ReportRunnable/DesignInstance available?

As far as I know you can get an element from the DesignInstance if you know the name of that element. I want to be able to traverse it no matter what. It is possible having elements with no name but only autogen IDs; so I would like to cover these cases by being able to traverse the report at runtime no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up at:

```
designHandle.getBody().getContents().get(0);
```